# Trying to stop form from redirecting after submit (return false & prevent.default are not working!)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The problem I've been trying to solve for hours and hours now is following: I cannot stop the redirecting of #myform action after the data has been submitted succesfully to database. I've tried multiple methods but none seem to work. I'm in dire need of help!

The code:

Html(mainview.php):

```
    <div id="submitAccordion">

    <form id="myForm" action="userFiles.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="accordionName" /><br />
        <input id="sub" type="submit" name="go"  />

    </form>

    <span id="result">  </span>

   </div>
```

Javascript(mainview_script.js):

```
 $("#sub").click(function () {

        var data = $("#myForm :input").serializeArray();

        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        data, function(info) {
        $("#result").html(info); } )
        }); 

        $("#myForm").submit(function () {

        return false;

        });
```

php(userFiles.php):

```
session_start();
require_once 'database.php';

if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO useraccordion (id, h3) VALUES (:id, :accordion)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':accordion', $_POST['accordionName']);
    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
       echo "Succesfully inserted";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error";
    }
}
```

I have tried ajax method, prevent.default etc, but none work!

Comment: make `input#sub` not `type="submit"`, just `type="button"`. you are both submitting the form and sending ajax request. most likely the js gets executed too late, already at the time of redirection. also remove `$("#myForm").submit(`

Comment: Use window. Redirect method in ajax success response.

Comment: Use window. Redirect method in ajax success response. - use window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move your $("#myForm").submit(... out of the click event so it is it's own thing. Then, pass in e into that function. So it would look like this...

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
});
$("#sub").click(function() {
    var data = $("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),data, function(info) {
        $("#result").html(info); 
    });
});
```

That will fix your immediate problem. My thought is... Do not even use a form for this. There is no reason to. You are posting the data via Ajax, so there is no reason to have a form that would submit. I would do something like this...

HTML...

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="form-item">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <button id="sub">Submit Form</button>
</div>
```

Javascript...

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
    var postData = {};
    //this is here to be dynamic incase you want to add more items....
    $("#form").find('input').each(function() {
          postData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "YOUR URL HERE",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#result").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I took note of your advice and your suggestion of not using form worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Finally, after 6 hours I'm done with this issue. I'm ashamed! Thanks for everyone who tried to help also!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Best of luck moving forward, JavaScript is a lot of fun, I'm sure you'll do great.

Answer (score 2):

Either change your input type to `button`

```
<input id="sub" type="button" name="go" value="Submit"/>
```

Or try this:

```
 $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Changed button to this :                                                                                                             
<button type="submit"  value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>   And still not working. coding <3

Comment: still this will redirect the page coz your button type is `submit`

Comment: I tried directly copy&pasting your input button and now the data isn't submitting to database either

Comment: There must be other issue somewhere. This is perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, I've tried multiple methods before coming here and after hours of trying I had to come here for help. Don't know where the issue was but the solution from Neglected Sanity worked, thank god! My code must be a mess. And thank you also for trying to help!

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is not required if you change input type to `button`.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to prevent deafult action on sub:

```
$("#sub").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $("#myForm :input").serializeArray();

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
                  data, function(info) {
                        $("#result").html(info); } )
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

That should stop the submission

Comment: I've tried preventDefault before, didn't work then, didn't work now. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting your form data via ajax or jquery then you should change your input type form 'submit' to 'button' type

```
<input id="sub" type="button" name="go" value="go"/>
```